# Can the maximum and minimum for $y=5\sin(5x+20)-2$ be found using algebra?

Tags: trigonometry

Here is what I know about $y=5\sin(5x+20)-2$:

1. General form of a sinusoidal function is; $y=A\sin(Bx-C)+D$
2. Amplitude $\lvert A \rvert=5$
3. Period $ \frac{2 \pi}{B}=\frac{2 \pi}{5}$
4. Midline $D = -2$
5. Horizontal shift $ \frac{C}{B}=\frac{-20}{5}=-4$

From this information I know the midpoint between the maximum and minimum is $-2$.  When I graph this function I know the $y$ values are $3$ for the maximum and $-7$ for the minimum.  Is there any way to substitute $3$ or $-7$ into the equation $y=5\sin(5x+20)-2$ to find the $x$ values?

I can use Desmos or a graphing calculator to find the $x$ values, but this is really the only way I can find the values.  I also find it difficult to graph this equation by hand.  I really have a hard time finding intercepts along with the maxima and minima.

[image]

Comment: Basically you are looking for the solutions of $\sin(5x+20)=1$ (or $\sin(5x+20)=-1$), i.e. $5x+20=2k\pi+\pi/2$ (or $5x+20=2k\pi-\pi/2$) for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, which is the same as $x=\frac{1}{5}\left(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}-20\right)$ (or $x=\frac{1}{5}\left(2k\pi-\frac{\pi}{2}-20\right)$) for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I don't know why people so often type `$u$=$v$` instead of `$u=v$` to get $u=v$, but I've fixed that in places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\sin t$ function takes values in $[-1,1]$. It takes the value $1$ when $t=\frac{\pi}{2}+2 k\pi, \,\,k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and it takes the value $-1$ when $t = -\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi, \,\,k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So, you function attains a maximum value of $3$ when $5x+20 =\frac{\pi}{2}+2 k\pi, \,\,k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and a minimum value of $-7$ when $5x+20 =-\frac{\pi}{2}+2 k\pi, \,\,k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is there anyway to find a minimum inside the period $\frac{2 \pi}{5}$?  Do you know of a good place to read more about the sin t function?

Comment: The period between $0, \frac{2 \pi}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can. Note that $-1 \le \sin(5x+20) \le 1$ and these bounds are achievable.